# Sendmail & IpTable Rules

Tags: iptables, firewall, sendmail, port

I need to setup IpTable Rules for a server with nginx, ssh and sendmail.
Now, the problem is, with my rules I can not send emails to other hosts anymore.
Emails to localhost do work, but sending to different servers does not, when the firewall is up.

I tried opening both Incoming and Outgoing Port 25 and DNS lookup ports, but nothing worked.
Any ideas?

**Update:**

Here are my rules:

```
#! /bin/sh
# firewall iptable rules

interface="eth0"

# first, deny all
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# open loopback device completely
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# open ssh ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i $interface --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o $interface --sport 22  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# open browser ports
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i $interface --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -o $interface --sport 80  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow your Linux box to send emails via port 25, you should allow it by adding a rule like:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Similarly for DNS traffic:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

If there is no such explicit rules, the traffic will be denied by default as the default policy is set to `DROP`.

**Update:**

Don't forget to allow the related/established connections using:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rules to your IPTables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer, to which yours really doesn't add anything useful.